# How do I order posns based on increasing posn-x values and posn-y values?

Tags: sorting, insert, scheme, racket

I have to sort based on increasing values of `posn-x` (ie. `(make-posn -1 2)` comes before `(make-posn 1 2)`. If values of `posn-x` are the same, then I have to consider `posn-y` and do the same.

A sample of what to expect is:

```
(check-expect (posn-sort (list (make-posn 2 6)
                               (make-posn -2 6)
                               (make-posn -2 -6)))
                         (list (make-posn -2 -6)
                               (make-posn -2 6)
                               (make-posn 2 6)))
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: hi @macy, have you tried anything yourself? can you show us your attempt and explain where/what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Actually I have previously showed all my work, if you click on edits, everything I previously typed would be there. There was more to the question but this is the only part I needed help with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sort` procedure, passing as parameters the list of positions and a comparator procedure:

```
(define (posn-sort lst)
  (sort lst compare-posn))
```

Of course, the trick is to write a proper comparator. It receives as parameters two positions, and [returns](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29):

> a true value if the first is less (i.e., should be sorted earlier) than the second.

For your case, that means that first we should compare the `x` values of the two positions, if that comparison is `false`, then we compare the `y` values. The procedure writes itself:

```
(define (compare-posn p1 p2)
  (or (< (posn-x p1) (posn-x p2))
      (< (posn-y p1) (posn-y p2))))
```

Comment: @macy did this post solve your question? if that's the case, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;) . Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).